Python find index of element in list based on evaluation of a function
I am trying to find the index of an item in a Python list based on the evaluation value of a lambda function (or other callable).
This would be similar to a combination of an .index() operation with a find_if operation.
Here is an example:
# self contains `self.list`
def find_index_where(self, id: int) -> int:

    # callable expression which tests a sub-member of some object `input`
    def lambda_callable(input, id):
        return input.id == id

    # extra work being done:
    # first find an `item` then find an `index` corresponding to `item`
    matched_item = next(item for item in self.list if lambda_callable(item, id))
    index = self.list.index(matched_item)
    return index

Is there a way to roll the "item finding" operation together with the "index finding" operation?

Since you are looking for the element in a different list than the one you want to retrieve the index from, I don't think you can shortcut this. If it were the same list you could use enumerate in the generator.

Sorry that's a my bad

Could you make that a [MRE], including example data, so we can test solutions?

@nocomment No, I cannot

Sad. Then I likewise cannot post my solutions.

@nocomment It seems other people were able to provide answers without your demands

And it seems other people are able to provide MREs. But if you don't want my solutions, that's ok.

@nocomment I don't want your solutions. I'm quite sure I'm not missing out on anything

you can use this :
def find_index_where(self, id: int) -> int:
    def lambda_callable(input, id):
        return input.id == id
    try:
        index = next(index for index, item in enumerate(self.list) if lambda_callable(item, id))
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError("Item not found in the list.")

    return index


As @Matthias said in the comments, you can use enumerate like the code below, which is more readable without using next.
def find_index_where(self, id: int) -> int:
      for index, item in enumerate(self.list):
        if lambda_callable(item, id):
          return index
      raise ValueError("Item with id not found in the list")

